# Is it possible to test iOS 8 Handoff feature with simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, ios8

Can I test Handoff with Simulator and one device, or can it only be tested with two physical devices?

Comment: have your tried? any joy?

Comment: yes tried ....... but continueUserActivity delegate method not called. And guys who are giving minus marking, if you know the answer then reply as well. Don't be panic for others.

Comment: Anybody confident for replying in YES or NO with reason.

Comment: As i've tested so far i can't achieve handoff between my macbook air and the iphone simulator. I know that in the physical device under the settings there is a checkbox that allows you to enable or disable handoff, but there is no such setting in the simulator. The same setting relies on my macbook under "General". Maybe the lack of that setting in the simulator is because doesn't support handoff..

Answer (score 7):

Apple's documentation:

[API Differences](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW16)

> Simulator APIs don’t have all the features that are available on a
>   device. For example, the APIs don’t offer:
>
> - Receiving and sending Apple push notifications
> - Privacy alerts for access to Photos, Contacts, Calendar, and Reminders
> - The UIBackgroundModes key
> - **Handoff support**
>
> In addition, Simulator doesn’t support the following frameworks:
>
> - External Accessory
> - Media Player
> - Message UI
> - In UIKit, the UIVideoEditorController class

Answer (score 5):

As far as i know and experienced, simulator doesn't give any option to enable Handoff or pair Bluetooth device.
Due to this, I believe what you asked is not possible.